# Cant connect to yahoo with getSymbols in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I write :

```
library(quantmod)  
getSymbols("AAPL")
```

I get   :

```
 Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : 
   Couldn't connect to server
```

My `sessionInfo`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)



attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-10 TTR_0.23-1      xts_0.9-7       zoo_1.8-0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1  tools_3.4.1     curl_2.7        grid_3.4.1      lattice_0.20-35
>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to rerun it a couple more times

Comment: I tried to rerun it several times and still get the same answer ...any suggestions?

Comment: The error suggests `curl` is unable to connect to the internet. Run this command and edit its output into your question: `w <- curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://finance.yahoo.com", curl::new_handle(verbose = TRUE))`.

Comment: I get  : Rebuilt URL to: https://finance.yahoo.com/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 87.248.118.23...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* After 4976ms connect time, move on!
* connect to 87.248.118.23 port 443 failed: Timed out
*   Trying 87.248.118.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* After 2359ms connect time, move on!
* connect to 87.248.118.22 port 443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to finance.yahoo.com port 443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://finance.yahoo.com", curl::new_handle(verbose = TRUE)) : 
  Couldn't connect to serve

Comment: May be your system admin is blocking the URL or proxy. not sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo! Finance API has been officially discontinued](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503).

You may want to use another source. For google: `getSymbols("AAPL", src = "google")`.

---

You might also want to try [quandl](https://www.quandl.com/tools/r), which fetchs data from many publishers. 
You can also store the data in a POSIXct indexed `xts` object, so you still can plot it with quantmod:

```
Quandl("SOURCE/SYMBOL", type="xts")
```

If you plan to do more than 50 daily calls, you would need a free API key, which don't have any restriction on the frequency or on the amount of your calls.